# How to display different data from the same table in Repeater that exists in many pages of the website?

Tags: sql, asp.net-controls

I have a Repeater that shows safety messages from the Safety Messages Table in the database. Since I will put this Repeater in many pages of the Website, I want to this Repeater to show different messages in each page. For example, if it shows message#1 in this page as a first message then message#2 and so on, it should show message#10 as a first message in the other web page and so on. So how to do that?

My query is very simple like this:

```
SELECT MessageID, MessageDesc, MessageAuthor FROM [SafetyMessage]
```

Is this issue related to the query? Or it can be done from the Repeater itself?

**UPDATE:**
***I want the repeater to show the data from the database in each page in different order***

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called "paging support".  Here is an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx) with an example of how to do it.

**Edit: Based on further information from OP...**

It sounds to me like what OP is asking for is paging and *sorting*.

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125145856/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020905-1.aspx) explains how to do paging and sorting with a repeater control.

Comment: I don't want paging support. I want to show items in different order. This is what I am looking for.